# Spnego Kerberos Spring SSO showing Kerberos validation not successful

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-batch, spring-security-kerberos

My WebSecurityConfiguration  class as follows-

```
package com.subhajit.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosClient;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import eu.europa.ecb.sis.adminmodule.security.DummyUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
                spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable();
    }

     @Bean
        public SpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
            return new SpnegoEntryPoint("/");
        }

      @Bean
        public SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
            SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter =
                    new SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
            try {
                filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //System.out("Failed to set AuthenticationManager on SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.", e);
                System.out.println("Failed to set AuthenticationManager on SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter");
            }
            return filter;
        }



    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider())
                .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider() {
        KerberosAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosAuthenticationProvider();
        SunJaasKerberosClient client = new SunJaasKerberosClient();
        client.setDebug(true);
        provider.setKerberosClient(client);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(dummyUserDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
        KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(dummyUserDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() {
        SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ticketValidator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
        ticketValidator.setServicePrincipal("HTTP/t-abc-def.def1.domain.net@DEF1.DOMAIN.NET");
        FileSystemResource fs = new FileSystemResource("G:/Applications/conf/krbuser.keytab");
        Assert.notNull(fs.exists(), "*.keytab key must exist. Without that security is useless.");
        ticketValidator.setKeyTabLocation(fs);
        ticketValidator.setDebug(true); // Turn off when it will works properly,
        return ticketValidator;
    }

    @Bean
    public DummyUserDetailsService dummyUserDetailsService() {
        return new DummyUserDetailsService();
    }
}
```

My base path in the properties is

spring.data.rest.basePath=/api

I am trying to hit the controller class as

t-abc-def.def1.domain.net/api/msd/mydata

My controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/msd")
public class MSDController{
@RequestMapping(value = "mydata/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Collection<DbData>> getData(final HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
}

}
```

When I am hitting the url it is showing

Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate YIIHuQYGKwYBBQUCoIIHr******

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not successful
    at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:494)
    at org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat80AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat80AgentValve.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: null
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:68)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:153)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.krb5.KrbCryptoException: Checksum failed
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decryptCTS(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    ... 87 common frames omitted
```

I have keytab file and my service principal already set in my domain controller. Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927316/spring-security-kerberos-ad-checksum-fail

Comment: I have found that the webservice is working from curl command but not accessible from browser. For curl it is automatically taken the logged in windows account but for chrome it is showing the above error

Comment: Have a look at https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM#chrome

Comment: Could you please update the question with your krb5 file and the setSpn -L output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass windows authentication(browser) from react application to Spnego Kerberos Spring SSO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573623/how-to-pass-windows-authenticationbrowser-from-react-application-to-spnego-ker)